# "Clicking" HTML element with button tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize

I am trying to enter CEP in the field in the link below and then press the "calcular" button which is given by a  tag and also of type "button." I think I've determined that mechanize won't get the job done, but even selenium isn't doing what I need it to. Below is my mechanize code.

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(False)
br.set_all_readonly(False)
br.set_debug_http(True)
br.set_debug_responses(True)
br.addheaders=[('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)]
br.open(prod_url)
print br.title()
print br.geturl()
br.select_form(nr=1)
br['postalCode']='05454-050'
br.submit()
print br.geturl()
sourceCode=BeautifulSoup(br.response().read(),'html.parser')
```

http://www.americanas.com.br/produto/113266366/fone-de-ouvido-philips-over-ear-branco-shl3000wt

Comment: You open to using other methods?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using selenium, you need to clear the placeholder then enter the postcode text with `send_keys`, to get the frete price etc.. we need to wait until that element is visible::

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def wait(dr, x, t):
    element = WebDriverWait(dr, t).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, x))
    )
    return element

dr = webdriver.Firefox()
dr.maximize_window()
dr.get("http://www.americanas.com.br/produto/113266366/fone-de-ouvido-philips-over-ear-branco-shl3000wt")
inp = dr.find_element_by_id("postalCode")
inp.clear()
inp.send_keys("05454050")
inp.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
ele = wait(dr, "table.tbl-freight-template tr td span.freight-value.info-freight", 20)
print(ele.text)
```

Running the above code would output:

```
R$ 18,45
```